# How can I raise a warning for optional argument in TypeScript in editor level

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, nextjs-image

In VsCode when using Image component from `next/image`, If you don't provide an alt value to image it gives warning. But it is optional.

How can I achieve same thing with my custom Image component?

Here is the warning message:[image]

Simple custom image component abstraction

```
type ImageProps = {
  src: string
  alt?: string
  width?: number
  height?: number
}

const CustomImage = ({src, alt, width, height} : ImageProps) => {
 return (...)
}
```

Comment: In the problems window you can see which extension is raising this warning message